# There is by now a captcha-problem

Tags: bug, captcha, error-message

[image]

Tried several times with several captchas. [This](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/136356/top-users-in-denmark) is the data explorer page I tried to access.

with space between :

[image]

To the non-believers :) :

[image]

#### System produced on:

Windows 7
Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146

Comment: You didn't type the second number?

Comment: Did you enter *all* digits? - 44782326888

Comment: Normally we dont have to.

Comment: @davidkonrad normally you have to type the whole including the space!

Comment: Stop downvoting. I am reporting an error. I have done this 100 times before as you suggest, thats why I make it an issue on meta. Is it so hard to understand?

Comment: Hmm, strange ... for me the captcha doesn't even show up ...

Comment: @Bart It showed me when I press the run query! and It works fine as expected

Comment: @bart - Now the data explorer page went through **without** captcha. So there is clearly a problem. And the data explorer reports data a month old.

Comment: No-repro. Works as expected for me.

Comment: @AsheeshR, I believe that. I guess the servers is out of sync, and the server dealing with capthas is out of sync with the server delevering the captcha questions. And that is a local issue, maybe only for the server serving us in northern europe. But still, it is an error.

Comment: People, please don't close this question as "can no longer be reproduced" just because you can't reproduce it. There is no problem in leaving this open.

Comment: I was not presented with a captcha when I tried it from a mobile device (with a different IP address than my laptop), so there *could* be a problem.

Comment: Could you add the details of the system you're using. Also if you previously only had to enter 1 of the two words that was a bug which may now have been fixed

Comment: @RichardTingle I always used only to enter the first 4 digits. I thought it was either one. If we are forced to enter the whole thing it tenders terror :-)

Comment: If I recall correctly the system only actually knows 1. It asks you to give both. The one it knows validates you and the one it doesn't is now know (I think a few different people all have to give the same answer). Given this, a wrong answer is deeply unhelpful but probably not detectable but it can detect no amswer at all

Comment: @RichardTingle, the above is when I was on a windows 7 box (playing civ) the reader was Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146

Comment: @RichardTingle, hard to believe it is a clientside problem. It is by 99.99999% certainty a problem with server replicance.

Comment: @david what basis have you for believing that? The system is always relevant information.  Especially when only certain people can reproduce it

Comment: My basis is, that there propably is millions of people using windows 7 and chrome, who is not discovering this problem. Remember, to begin with my question was downvoted. I believe it is a async failure on one or mere servers, think about @Martin R's experience. he is from Germany, It is maybe only here in northern Europe we see this, and the rest of the world go free.

Comment: Then add your location also. Add as much information as possible. Don't find reasons to remove information,  find reasons to add it

Comment: Albertslund. Copenhagen. Denmark. Windows 7, chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 - but I really dont think it makes a difference. You are in the [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) area now.

Comment: @MartinR - Were you connecting via https? If so the Captcha doesn't show.

Comment: @MartinSmith, gee have you lost your minds? "connecting via https" ???  Consider the fact that something on SO is not working as it should.

Comment: @davidkonrad - No idea what point you're trying to make. I googled "stack exchange data explorer" at first as I didn't notice the link in your question. The google result is an https link. The captcha is blocked by Chrome for https://data.stackexchange.com/ as it is an http resource.

Comment: @MartinSmith, fair enough. But here we are talking about totally normal access which is failing, things I have done many times before - and its failing for some other people also, not failing for others - and the rest getting some weird results. I succeded the capctha, but the results was a month old, just to give an example of the weirdness.

Comment: I wonder, what CDN broker does stackoverflow use, and does that broker had problems recently, maybe the past 4-5 hours?

Comment: @davidkonrad - Why wouldn't my answer explain it? Your question states that you often don't fill it in correctly so its quite likely that you failed the Captcha initially presented to you.

Comment: @MartinSmith Because other people expericence weirdness too, and because I have not changed my behavior - suddenly it does not work. Should the difference be lack of protocol and certificate? I think not.

Comment: @davidkonrad - But your behaviour is to only fill in one of the numbers isn't it? That means you get a 50% chance of failing. And it looks as though when you fail once that dooms the Captcha forever on this site until you manually refresh to get a new challenge (bug).

Comment: @MartinSmith, gee - look below. The problem is reproduceable, you have dunnit yourself.

Comment: That's my answer below. I reproduced it by *initially getting the challenge wrong,*

Comment: @MartinSmith, "I reproduced it by initially getting the challenge wrong", no - you reproduce by deliberately force the error. This is not what normally happening when you just type the numbers. As I did.

Comment: @animuson regarding your deleted answer the unknown number can be either of the two. It is an attempt to digitise house numbers from street view http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/04/04/google_recaptcha_street_view/

Comment: @Martin, as for *"the unknown number can be either of the two"*, I don't think so. This reCAPTCHA thing is heavily based on statistics. When showing you the two captcha's, Google is already confident about one of them, and its confidence about the other might affect how much of an error you can make for that other one. For animuson apparently others already entered the same value for the long number, so typing only that is fine. And the OP often was lucky with just the short number. It seems either the rules have been tightened, or Google is showing more "new" challenges?

Comment: (All that said, I still agree with you that the problem is probably caused by the captcha not being refreshed on error, @Martin.)

Comment: Oh, @Martin, only now I read your linked reference. Never knew (and wondering if it's true) that one of the images is generated, but it's the same idea indeed.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Left or right can be unknown, but one is always a similarly generated random string of characters.  In OP's question, the RHS are all generated check images that MUST be correct in order to pass the captcha.  In your answer, it's on the LHS.  You can literally type anything for the other value (I've never tried not entering something, so I don't know if that is an option).  It is always trivial to identify the check image, anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

Reproed here as well

[image]

Note before typing in the correct numbers as above I deliberately typed in wrong ones and submitted. I expected the Captcha to change after the failure and present a new challenge but it didn't.

Maybe the server side expects a new challenge but this isn't refreshed client side?

Clicking the refresh button and trying again with the new challenge it succeeded.

Comment: Indeed, on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha it does refresh on error.

Comment: @Arjan - And I've used ReCaptcha myself on sites and I'm pretty sure it is supposed to. The last two pictures in the question show the OP tried multiple times for the same captcha as well.

Comment: _Note before typing in the correct numbers as above I deliberately typed in wrong ones and submitted. I expected the Captcha to change after the failure but it didn't._ does not help deliberately entering the correct numbers for the first time.

Comment: Of course you can "reproduce" the error by deliberately doing so. As clarified many times, this is not a bad user behavior problem. This problem is serverside. Thats why I raise the problem on meta. And I think the problem is local, eg northern europe.

Comment: @davidkonrad, in your question you *also* typed the wrong answer the first time. It's not enough (anymore) to just type one; [try for yourself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/captcha). I feel Martin pinpointed the problem just fine. (And he's not saying it's *your* problem. Relax.)

Comment: @Arjan, where did I typed the wrong answer? Is 4478 not 4478?

Comment: @davidkonrad `4478 = 4478` but `'2326888' != ''`.